# "No site generator found" when renaming index.Rmd

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown

When I

1. create a fresh bookdown project in Rstudio,
2. rename the `index.Rmd` to, say, `prep.Rmd` and customize the `rmd_files` key in `_bookdown.yml` accordingly (as described in the official [bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html)) to:

   ```yaml
   rmd_files:
     - "prep.Rmd"
     - "01-intro.Rmd"
     - "02-literature.Rmd"
     - "03-method.Rmd"
     - "04-application.Rmd"
     - "05-summary.Rmd"
     - "06-references.Rmd"
   ```
3. and then try to build the book using RStudio's  <kbd>Build Book</kbd> button from the *Build* pane, the following error message is displayed:

   ```
   ==> rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')

   Error in rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = "UTF-8") : 
     No site generator found.
   Execution halted

   Exited with status 1.
   ```

**Is there any way to make RStudio's  <kbd>Build Book</kbd> button work again while retaining the above customizations?**

Further observations:

- As soon as I rename `prep.Rmd` back to `index.Rmd` and adjust the `rmd_files` key accordingly, the book builds fine using RStudio's  <kbd>Build Book</kbd> button.
- This issue only occurs when renaming the first bookdown chapter `index.Rmd`, renaming any of the subsequent chapters works as supposed.
- The error seems to have to do with the first of the [two requirements of the `rmarkdown::render_site()` function](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/rmarkdown/reference/render_site.html#details) RStudio's  <kbd>Build Book</kbd> button relies on:

  > There are two requirements for a directory to be rendered as a website:
  >
  > 1. It must contain either an "index.Rmd" or "index.md" file.
  > 2. It must contain a site configuration file ("_site.yml").

  Interestingly, the second "requirement" isn't fulfilled in a default fresh bookdown project either, i.e. there's no `_site.yml` file. So it isn't clear to an outsider like me why I should care about the first requirement if the bookdown documentation doesn't say anything about it (and it doesn't!).

Of course I can live *without renaming the default `index.Rmd`* of my bookdown project. But I still want to properly understand what I'm doing (and what I should refrain from). Since I don't know if this should be considered a bug or just a lack of proper documentation, I'm asking here about it instead of directly filing a bug report. If it's the latter, the official [bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html) should be updated I guess.

---

My setup (output of `xfun::session_info()`):

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, RStudio 1.2.1335

Locale:
  LC_CTYPE=de_CH.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_CH.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_CH.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_CH.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_CH.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_CH.UTF-8      
  LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_CH.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

Package version:
  askpass_1.1        assertthat_0.2.1   backports_1.1.4    base64enc_0.1.3    BH_1.69.0.1        bookdown_0.12      broom_0.5.2        callr_3.3.1        cellranger_1.1.0   cli_1.1.0         
  clipr_0.7.0        colorspace_1.4-1   compiler_3.6.1     crayon_1.3.4       curl_4.0           DBI_1.0.0          dbplyr_1.4.2       digest_0.6.20      dplyr_0.8.3        ellipsis_0.2.0.1  
  evaluate_0.14      fansi_0.4.0        forcats_0.4.0      fs_1.3.1           generics_0.0.2     ggplot2_3.2.0      glue_1.3.1         graphics_3.6.1     grDevices_3.6.1    grid_3.6.1        
  gtable_0.3.0       haven_2.1.1        highr_0.8          hms_0.5.0          htmltools_0.3.6    httr_1.4.0         jsonlite_1.6       knitr_1.23         labeling_0.3       lattice_0.20-38   
  lazyeval_0.2.2     lubridate_1.7.4    magrittr_1.5       markdown_1.0       MASS_7.3.51.4      Matrix_1.2.17      methods_3.6.1      mgcv_1.8.28        mime_0.7           modelr_0.1.4      
  munsell_0.5.0      nlme_3.1-140       openssl_1.4.1      packrat_0.5.0      pillar_1.4.2       pkgconfig_2.0.2    plogr_0.2.0        plyr_1.8.4         prettyunits_1.0.2  processx_3.4.1    
  progress_1.2.2     ps_1.3.0           purrr_0.3.2        R6_2.4.0           RColorBrewer_1.1.2 Rcpp_1.0.2         readr_1.3.1        readxl_1.3.1       rematch_1.0.1      reprex_0.3.0      
  reshape2_1.4.3     rlang_0.4.0        rmarkdown_1.14     rstudioapi_0.10    rvest_0.3.4        scales_1.0.0       selectr_0.4.1      splines_3.6.1      stats_3.6.1        stringi_1.4.3     
  stringr_1.4.0      sys_3.2            tibble_2.1.3       tidyr_0.8.3        tidyselect_0.2.5   tidyverse_1.2.1    tinytex_0.14       tools_3.6.1        utf8_1.1.4         utils_3.6.1       
  vctrs_0.2.0        viridisLite_0.3.0  whisker_0.3.2      withr_2.1.2        xfun_0.8           xml2_1.2.1         yaml_2.2.0         zeallot_0.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the name of the first `Rmd` or `md` file. Here is how to find this given the source code of `rmarkdown`:

- The exception you observer is thrown in `render_site` when `site_generator` returns `NULL`, c.f. [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/37bcb8fe775f44b9a3d4c60990e849dee4041e8e/R/render_site.R#L213-L217).
- In `site_generator` the possible file names `index.Rmd` and `index.md` are hard-coded, c.f. [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/37bcb8fe775f44b9a3d4c60990e849dee4041e8e/R/render_site.R#L245-L247).
- An alternative to using `_site.yml` is to use `site: ...` in the YAML header of the index file, c.f. [GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/37bcb8fe775f44b9a3d4c60990e849dee4041e8e/R/render_site.R#L254-L263)