# With bookdown: "No site generator found", yet all appears correct...?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, bookdown

I have been happily enjoying bookdown for some time now... but today, when I try to `Build Book` I keep getting this message:

```
Error in rmarkdown::render_site(output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book",  : 
No site generator found.
```

It was working just yesterday.

I am aware of [this message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378295/no-site-generator-found-when-renaming-index-rmd) and [a similar message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488681/rmarkdownrender-site-error-in-rmarkdownrender-site-no-site-generator-f), but nothing there seems to help (at least to my naïve eyes).

I *do* have a `index.Rmd` file, for instance, which *does* includes the line `site:bookdown::bookdown_site`.

I have updated to the latest R and RStudio releases, and updated my packages. I changed my `index.Rmd` file to a minimum, but the error persists.

I am in the correct working (Project) directory. I redownloaded the [repos from Github](https://github.com/PeterKDunn/DistTheory) to a fresh directory and tried again, but the problem persist.

And if I type this:

```
rmarkdown::site_generator()
```

...it returns `NULL`. If I type (on my Windows machine here at home)

```
system("dir")
```

...I do indeed see the `index.Rmd` file listed (as I should). I tried renaming it, and then re-renaming it back to `index.Rmd` which (predictably) did nothing to help.

So, yeah. The problem is 'real', but I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried all that I know... to no avail. Can anyone help? Please?

(And, of course, our Semester 1 start on Monday here in Australia, so this is untimely :-<)

P.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.2.2  bookdown_0.32   fastmap_1.1.0   cli_3.4.1       htmltools_0.5.3 tools_4.2.2    
 [7] rstudioapi_0.14 yaml_2.3.6      rmarkdown_2.20  knitr_1.42      xfun_0.34       digest_0.6.30  
[13] rlang_1.0.6     evaluate_0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space after `site:`, i.e.,

```
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
```

Comment: Thank Yihui. I added said space, but it still does not work. (In any case, it had been working until yesterday, and nothing had changed; perhaps it was just a typo on my part.) So the problem persists...

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue: I opened R (*not* RStudio), and ran `update.packages()` there.

I had previously updated package in RStudio. But updating them in the R console seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Good to know that you have solved the problem!